# If lim $f(x)g(x)$ exist for $x\to 0$, f,g belongs to R, and $f(x),g(x)\ge0$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\operatorname{lim}$$f(x)g(x)$ exist for x$\to$0, f,g belongs to R, and $f(x),g(x)\ge0$

Does that mean that atleast one of this limits exist?

1. $\operatorname{lim}$ $f(x)$ for $x\to 0$
2. $\operatorname{lim}$ $g(x)$ for $x\to 0$

Comment: Please use MathJax, בבקשה תרשום בכתיב מתמטי.

Comment: take $\sin(1/x)+2$ and its inverse

Comment: You'll find questions on math.stackexchange will get more helpful answers if you include some context. What have you tried so far? What are some other facts you know that might be related?

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider the two folowing functions:

$
f(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
      1, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      0, & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} 
  \end{cases}
$

and
$
g(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
      0, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      1, & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} 
  \end{cases}$

$g(x)$and $f(x)$ are $\geq 0$, and $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, same as $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} g(x)$.

But $f(x)g(x) = 0$ and so, $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} f(x)g(x)$ exists and is equal to $0$.